# Dificuldade em formular query

Tags: sql-server-2008

Em um sistema existem **parcelas** cadastradas . Os **usuários** podem `classificar` as **parcelas** por **famíliaDeParcela** sendo que cada **usuário** tem suas próprias **famíliaDeParcela**.

As **parcelas** são comuns a todos.

Tenho 4 tabelas:

**Usuario** que tem `cod_usuario` **PK**
**Parcela** que tem `cod_parcela` **PK**
**FamiliaDeParcelas** que tem `cod_usuario` **FK** e `cod_familia` **PK**
**Parcela_FamiliaParcela** que tem `cod_familia`**FK** , `cod_parcela` **FK** , e uma **PK** composta por `cod_familia` e `cod_parcela`

Exemplo de uso :

Temos 5 parcelas cadastradas

```
    Horas extras além da 6a,
    Horas extras além da 8a,
    danos morais,
    danos materiais,
    periculosidade.
```

O usuário 1 cadastra as famílias `HORAS EXTRAS`, `DANOS` e `OUTROS` que pertencerão só a ele e então pode classificar

```
    Horas extras além da 6a --> HORAS EXTRAS 
    Horas extras além da 8a --> HORAS EXTRAS
    danos morais ---> DANOS
    danos materiais ---> DANOS
    periculosidade ----> OUTROS
```

E o usuário 2 cadastra as famílias `SALARIAL` e `INDENIZATÓRIA` que pertencerão só a ele e então pode classificar

```
    Horas extras além da 6a --> SALARIAL
    Horas extras além da 8a --> SALARIAL
    danos morais ---> INDENIZATÓRIA
    danos materiais ---> INDENIZATÓRIA
    periculosidade ----> NULL ( DEIXAR SEM CLASSIFICAR )
```

Quando um usuário estiver usando preciso `listar` todas as **parcelas** com sua **FamiliaDeParcela** e caso não tenha sido classificada , retornar só os dados da **parcela**, mas só desse **usuario** !

Se faço

```
     select * 
     from Parcela p 
     left outer join Parcela_FamiliaDeParcelas pf ON pf.cod_parcela = p.cod_parcela 
     left outer join FamiliaDeParcelas f on f.cod_familia = pf.cod_familia and f.cod_usuario = @codusuario
```

Com essa query pra cada classificação que o **usuário** faz ela retorna 1 ocorrencia extra pra cada classificação da mesma parcela que outro **usuário** fez ( porém com `null` nos dados da **familia** )

Se adiciono no final um `where f.cod_usuario = @codusuario` ele retorna só as **parcelas** do **usuário** , mas não as **parcelas** não classificadas

O que devo fazer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era o seguinte:

Como comecei a query **from Parcela p**  e fazia um **left outer join Parcela_FamiliaParcela** usando `p.cod_parcela` a query retornava todos os registros que tinham `p.cod_parcela` incluíndo os dos outros usuários .

Percebi isso e então comecei a query from **FamiliaDeParcela fp** e fiz o um left join usando `fp.cod_familia` e `@codusuario`  seguido de um right join pra listar todas as **parcelas** e assim funcionou direitinho !

A query final ficou:

```
    SELECT *  FROM FamiliaDeParcelas 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PARCELA_FAMILIAPARCELAS f ON f.cod_familia = FamiliaDeParcelas.cod_familia 
    AND FamiliaDeParcelas.cod_usuario = @codusuario 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN Parcela ON f.cod_parcela = Parcela.cod_parcela
```

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta está bem confusa (rs), mas pelo que entendi, acho que há erro de cardinalidade. Veja na imagem abaixo o modelo relacional das tabelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se estiver correto, você gravará o campo `cod_familia` na tabela `Parcela` como uma FK (Chave Estrangeira), assim não haverá a necessidade da tabela `Parcela_FamiliaParcela`. E também gravará o campo `cod_usuario` na tabela `Parcela` como uma FK.

E sua consulta poderá ficar assim:

```
select *
from parcela p
left join FamiliaDeParcelas fp on (fp.cod_familia = p.cod_familia)
inner join Usuario u on (pf.cod_usuario = u.cod_usuario)
where pf.cod_usuario = @cod_usuario
```

Espero ter colaborado!

Comment: O diagrama que você fez está correto Eduardo, porém uma parcela não pertence a um usuário e por isso não posso colocar em parcela uma FK_USUARIO . Também não posso colocar FK_Familia na parcela uma vez que ela não pertence a um usuário e cada usuário pode fazer sua própria classificação . Se fizesse isso eu teria que recadastrar todas as parcelas para todos os usuários . ex parcela1 , usuario1 ,familia1  / parcela1 , usuario2,familia2

Comment: Vou tentar clarificar aqui , vamos considerar que Parcela = Produto , FamiliaDeParcela = Categoria em um sistema que todos os usuarios podem vender  Arroz , chocolate e refrigerante . um usuário pode criar uma categoria alimentos e classificar Arroz, chocolate e Refrigerante como alimentos .  um segundo usuário cria 3 categorias comida,doce e bebida , e classifica arroz como comida , chocolate como doce e refrigerante como bebida .

Comment: Eduardo, consegui solucionar usando right join !  Muito obrigado pela ajuda cara , fiquei extremamente contente por ter recebido sua resposta com o trabalho de fazer o diagrama e tudo . Logo vou deletar essa pergunta porque acho que ela não ajuda muita gente e realmente ta confusa . Mas não antes de agradecer . Brigadasso !!

Comment: Kkkkk. Pelo seu primeiro comentário o que eu ir realmente não ia funcionar. Mas que bom que conseguiu. Estamos aqui pra isso, para tentar ajudar. Fica na paz.

Comment: Foi a primeira vez que tive que usar right join na vida !  Tive que começar a query  from FamiliaDeParcela pra então fazer o join na tabela de união usando FamiliaDeParcela.id e não Parcela.id  e como tinha que listar todas as parcelas right join Parcela no final , feito isso funcionou certinho ! \o//

Answer (score 0):

Veja se assim resolve o seu problema:

```
select * from `Parcela_FamiliaParcela` `pfp`
left join `FamiliaDeParcelas` `fdp` on (`fdp`.`cod_familia`=`pfp`.`cod_familia`) 
left join `Usuario` `u` on(`u`.`cod_usuario`=`fdp`.`cod_usuario`)
left join `Parcela` `p` on (`p`.`cod_parcela`=`pfp`.`cod_parcela`)
where `u`.`cod_usuario`=@cod_user
```

Comment: Ivan , acredito que assim só vai retornar as parcelas que foram classificadas , além disso não teria a necessidade de unir a tabela usuário uma vez que os dados do usuário só viriam quando u.cod_usuario e  fdp.cod_usuario fossem iguais , logo where fdp.cod_usuario = @cod_user daria no mesmo

Comment: A query que eu fiz é pra trazer tudo na relação baseado no usuário (você pode tirar a condição `where`. E tudo que não precisar). O que você acredita, só vai valer se você executar a query primeiro, depois tire suas conclusões. Pois acredito que você está enganado.

Comment: A união "left join" não é limitadora.

Comment: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/uniao-png--2 Segue sua query executada , aconteceu exatamente o que falei... tenho 109 parcelas cadastradas , so listou as 2 classificadas pra esse usuário

Comment: pela imagem qualquer um pode ver que não é a minha query... desculpe.

Comment: não, minha query, tem : * não está pegando 2 campos. Além disso, a imagem não está completa. Então ela não prova os fatos, além disso, não se trata de humildade, a questão é ser claro e transparente. Eu não vejo isso na forma que vc se expressa. Não quis te ofender, só que a falta de humildade partiu de você, quando você pré julgou a minha query, pois aqui estamos empenhados em ajudar o outro.

Comment: se minha opinião não atende a seu propósito, não tem porque questioná-la, simplesmente a descarte. Assim como eu faço quando não considero útil. Eu não perco meu tempo. Assim caminha a Humilnidade.

Comment: Ivan , segue sua query executada ao lado da query que usei pra resolver o problema . Lembrando que a quantidade de campos selecionados não interfere no retorno . https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/imag-png